# javascript sorting algorithm not working - anything obvious i'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, sorting, angularjs

```
function MyController($scope) {
    var singleSort = [
        { "text": "Second", "a": 2 },
        { "text": "Fifth", "a": 5 },
        { "text": "First", "a": 1 },
        { "text": "Fourth", "a": 4 },
        { "text": "Third", "a": 3 }
    ];    

    var multipleSort = [
        { "text": "Second", "a": 1, "b": 2 },
        { "text": "Fifth", "a": 2, "b": 2 },
        { "text": "First", "a": 1, "b": 1 },
        { "text": "Fourth", "a": 2, "b": 1 },
        { "text": "Third", "a": 1, "b": 3 }
    ];

    var singleSortIterator = function(item) {
        return item.a;
    };    

    var multipleSortIterator = function(item) {
        return [item.a, item.b];
    };

    var singleSortReversedIterator = function(item) {
        return -item.a;
    };    

    var multipleSortReversedIterator = function(item) {
        return -[item.a, item.b];
    };    

    $scope.singleSort = _.sortBy(singleSort, singleSortIterator);     
    $scope.multipleSort = _.sortBy(multipleSort, multipleSortIterator);   
    $scope.singleSortReversed = _.sortBy(singleSort, singleSortReversedIterator);     
    $scope.multipleSortReversed = _.sortBy(multipleSort, multipleSortReversedIterator);   
}
```

​

The sorting algorithms are all working apart from the multipleSortReversed. Is there anything obvious wrong here?

http://jsfiddle.net/andybooth/QEBUx/

Results I'm getting are

```
Single sort
First
Second
Third
Fourth
Fifth
Multiple sort
First
Second
Third
Fourth
Fifth
Single sort (reversed)
Fifth
Fourth
Third
Second
First
Multiple sort (reversed)
Second
Fifth
First
Fourth
Third
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through underscore's source? If there's a bug you can report it to their [git hub repository](https://github.com/documentcloud/underscore/) and be a hero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://linqjs.codeplex.com seems to work well for multiple ordering http://jsfiddle.net/andybooth/caQjf/.

```
$scope.singleSortReversed = Enumerable.From(singleSort).OrderByDescending(orderByA).ToArray();   
$scope.multipleSortReversed = Enumerable.From(multipleSort).OrderByDescending(orderByA).ThenByDescending(orderByB).ToArray();
```

However, a solution using underscorejs would still be useful. I believe the suggested [-item.a, -item.b] from @cuzzae still returns the items in the wrong order, not reversed, as required.

Comment: Why do you think that "cuzzea"'s solution would return wrong order?

Comment: @GermannArlington Cuzzea's solution does not reverse the order of the items - see http://jsfiddle.net/QEBUx/5/

Answer (score 2):

I don't think uderscore can sort by multiple properties but I've implemented multi sort using plain javascript sort function

```
var helper = function(x,y) {
  var r = 0;
  if(x.a > y.a) {r+=10;}
  if(x.a < y.a) {r-=10;}
  if(x.b > y.b) {r+=1;}
  if(x.b < y.b) {r-=1;}
  return r;
}

var asc = [{a:2,b:1},{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:2}].sort(function(x,y) {
  return helper(x,y);
});

var desc = [{a:2,b:1},{a:1,b:2},{a:1,b:1},{a:2,b:2}].sort(function(x,y) {
  return -1 * helper(x,y);
});
```

The main idea is in helper. You need to make sure the values that get returned are in the correct order based on the property priority sorting.
possible values: 11,10,1,0,-1,-10,-11.

Answer (score 1):

What I can see at a glance is

```
var multipleSortReversedIterator = function(item) {
    return -[item.a, item.b]; // will return NaN
    // change to return [-item.a, -item.b];
};
```

Comment: `-[a, b]` will actually return `NaN`.

Comment: @cuzzea [-item.a, -item.b] returns items in the same order as [item.a, item.b] http://jsfiddle.net/QEBUx/5/

Comment: @Tom It seems that sortBy() does not interpret returned array correctly. As an easy workaround I would suggest  
`var multipleSortReversedIterator = function(item) {
    return -(item.a * 1000 + item.b); // will return NaN
};
`
I don't understand why forward iterator works correctly and the reverse does not.